# What is a good free utility to merge multiple tiff pages into one file?

Tags: pdf, editing, tiff

I'm looking for a free tiff editor that will allow me to combine multiple tiffs into one multiple page document using a GUI.  Windows 2000 used to ship with the Kodak Image Editor which allowed exactly this, but this utility no longer ships with windows.

I'd be willing to convert the tiffs to PDF if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to join the TIFF files, here's a free and portable tool that does just that:

> **[FaxTool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/PDF/FaxTool.shtml)** is a simple utility designed to help you split and join
>   TIFF and PDF files. You just simply
>   drag your files onto the interface to
>   split or join.

[image]

Comment: you're more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Discovered a few weeks ago that Sharepoint Designer 2007 has Microsoft Document Image Viewer as an [optional item](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21581).

It's a full TIFF editor/viewer and it did not require a MS Office base install in our testing.

- Open a shell viewer
- Drag your files over
- Merge from there

The merge does not bloat the files as was mentioned about FaxTool. I use the MODI API for a lot of automated TIFF manipulations via .NET. Merging TIFF through the API is actually fairly easy. Not sure if you wanted automated or manual. This should suit both.